# Are TypeScript 2.0 definition files backwards compatible?

Tags: typescript

I want to write a TypeScript library. I want to use 2.0 because, you know, it's the newest and it has a pretty cool set of features. However, I'm worried the majority of people (who probably still use 1.8-) won't be able to use it.

Are TypeScript 2.0 `d.ts` definition files backwards compatible with version 1.8? If not, is there a set of best practices I can follow to ensure compatibility? Failing that, can I do anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript 2.0 definition files are compatible with 1.8 as long as you don't expose any 2.0-specific features (such as `readonly` or numeric literal types).

The simplest thing to do would be to develop as normal, and use an `npm`-installed copy of the 1.8 compiler to validate that it's still able to parse the .d.ts file. Some other people in this situation have hooked in some Regexp replaces into their build chain to strip out a few 2.0-only features like `readonly` from their .d.ts files.

In the future there might be a tool that downlevels 2.0-specific features into their nearest 1.8-compatible equivalents, but no one has written it yet (FWIW it'd be relatively simple).

---

### List of 2.0-specific features you might find in a .d.ts file

- The `never` type
- The explicit `null` and `undefined` types
- Numeric and enum literal types (e.g. `interface I { x: 0 }`)
- `this` types in function expressions and function types (e.g. `f(this: something)`)
- UMD global definitions (`export as namespace g`)
- `readonly`
- Optional properties in classes
- Private and protected constructors

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful if you could point towards a list of incompatible features or write one yourself

Comment: Added a list that should be nearly complete

Comment: Thank you. I hope others will benefit from this question as well.